# '-1' overflow in constant expression while compiling OpenJDK 12.0.1 with gcc 7

Tags: gcc, macros, integer-overflow

I'm trying to compile OpenJDK 12.0.1 from scratch for an embedded x86_64 environment, and gcc 7 is throwing an error.

```
src/hotspot/share/utilities/globalDefinitions.hpp:969:39: warning: integer overflow in expression [-Woverflow]
 #define right_n_bits(n)   (nth_bit(n) - 1)
                                       ^
src/hotspot/share/oops/markOop.hpp:142:37: note: in expansion of macro ‘right_n_bits’
          ,hash_mask               = right_n_bits(hash_bits),
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
src/hotspot/share/utilities/globalDefinitions.hpp:969:42: error: overflow in constant expression [-fpermissive]
 #define right_n_bits(n)   (nth_bit(n) - 1)
```

And the code looks like:

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Utility functions for bitfield manipulations

const intptr_t AllBits    = ~0; // all bits set in a word
const intptr_t NoBits     =  0; // no bits set in a word
const jlong    NoLongBits =  0; // no bits set in a long
const intptr_t OneBit     =  1; // only right_most bit set in a word

// get a word with the n.th or the right-most or left-most n bits set
// (note: #define used only so that they can be used in enum constant definitions)
#define nth_bit(n)        (((n) >= BitsPerWord) ? 0 : (OneBit << (n)))
#define right_n_bits(n)   (nth_bit(n) - 1)
#define left_n_bits(n)    (right_n_bits(n) << (((n) >= BitsPerWord) ? 0 : (BitsPerWord - (n))))
```

Code reference [here](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk-updates/jdk12u/file/b58f3dee17d1/src/hotspot/share/utilities/globalDefinitions.hpp#l974).  This code has existed for a few versions and is also in the upcoming version OpenJDK 13.

I understand that:

```
#define right_n_bits(n)   (nth_bit(n) - 1)
```

is an error because '-1' could overflow the bounds of the particular type.  Normally the solution would be either to include a cast in the macro.

But, the programmers are clearly doing something special here so that they can handle both word and long in the same set of macros.

What's the appropriate way to handle this? Is there a simple solution or do I need to tell gcc to ignore this type of error?

Comment: Avoid bit manipulation of signed numbers. Unsigned should be OK. Not sure what exactly is achieved by `-0` though, it's the same as 0 and is by no means an "all bits set" number.

Comment: Thanks.  It's not `-0` but `~0` (bitwise NOT) so it is actually "all bits set" regardless of type.  How do I specify an unsigned number if I don't have the type at the point the macro is defined?

Comment: Sorry, small font, bad eyes. You do have the type. It's the type of OneBit that ultimately overflows. It should be uintptr_t (and all other bit mask constants should be unsigned too).